# No grub menu on booting

Tags: grub2, grub, manjaro, boot-loader

No Grub menu on booting!

I am using Manjaro no dual booting but multi-able Manjaro kernel versions, GPT UEFI installation.

I have tried `update-grup && install-grup` but no success.

It is important to mention that my SSD is encrypted, will this matter?

Please ask me for any more information.

Comment: Try changing grub configuration file from (# changes to comment so easy to change back if needed) `#GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden` to new line:
`GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu` and update grub. its `sudo update-grub`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @[oldfred](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/145882/oldfred)'s comment. That did it.

```
sudo vim /etc/default/grub  # Change GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden to GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
sudo update-grub
```